# Apache Solr drupal module, trigger for indexing new node

Tags: php, solr, drupal-6

I'm running drupal 6 and the Apache solr module (version = "6.x-1.6"). The apache solr index version is  1.40. I currently have a "real" cron job, which calls the cron.php file every half hour, in order to index new nodes (and remove deleted ones etc).

I was wondering.. is it possible to implement a hook or similar so that when creating a node, it will automatically index that node (and delete/update etc)? Such that you don't need to call cron.php periodically?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing hook_nodeapi() or something could be a solution but a messy solution, I think it's not what you want.

You have better to execute a specific cron job for index building and solr commit.

@see https://drupal.org/node/269381